# How to save pytest report to S3 directly

Tags: amazon-s3, pytest

we are using this code to save test report

```
def pytest_configure(config):

config._metadata = None
config.option.htmlpath = pytest.PROJECT_DIR.joinpath(os.getenv("REPORT_DIR")).joinpath("report.html")
```

But, we do not want to save it in local any more, we want to save it to S3 directly.

Are there any ways to save to S3 or any aws service to be able to store test report? I know that this report have to save to local and then upload to S3.

Answer (score 0):

For uploading pytest logs / reports to an S3 bucket, I demoed that in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-sno20R9P0&t=768s for a framework I created, [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase), which combines pytest and Selenium.

The specific code for that can be found here: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/seleniumbase/core/s3_manager.py (and uses `boto3` now instead of `boto`, which was originally used when that video was created).

First you need credentials:

```py
S3_LOG_BUCKET = "[S3 BUCKET NAME]"
S3_SELENIUM_ACCESS_KEY = "[S3 ACCESS KEY]"
S3_SELENIUM_SECRET_KEY = "[S3 SECRET KEY]"
```

Then you can initialize the connection:

```py
import boto3

conn = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=S3_SELENIUM_ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=S3_SELENIUM_SECRET_KEY,
)
```

Then you can upload a file:

```py
file_name = "report.html"  # (S3 destination) - Change as needed
file_path = "report.html"  # (Local filepath) - Change as needed

upload_key = conn.resource("s3").Object(S3_LOG_BUCKET, file_name)
content_type = "text/html"

upload_key.Bucket().upload_file(
    file_path,
    file_name,
    ExtraArgs={"ACL": "public-read", "ContentType": content_type},
)
```

If you don't want the report on a publicly accessible URL, modify the `ExtraArgs` line.

Those are the main parts. SeleniumBase also uploads an index file that shows all files that have been uploaded for a `pytest` run to S3.